# How to obtain the screen's height position in a long html page?

Tags: javascript, position, screen, sliding

[image]

I have a sliding screen on a long HTML page with left and right columns. How can I obtain the height position of the screen in the HTML page, knowing users use sliding bars? I need this to slide the left and right column content to follow users' movement. Thanks.

P.S.: I am using JQuery (if it helps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scrollTop` to find the vertical scroll position of any DOM element.

`$('#element').scrollTop()`

Some other useful functions: `scrollLeft()` , `offset()` , `position()`